# Show a specific dropdownList based on selected VALUE from another dropdownList

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net

I have 3 dropdownlists and each inside its own DIV.

The DIVs are called **fromCity**, **WithinStateLimits** and **OutOfState**.

What I am trying to accomplish with the jQuery script below is that if a user selects from the dropdownList inside the **fromCity** DIV, hide the other two DIVs.

If user selects from the dropdownList inside the **WithinStateLimits** DIV, then the other two DIVs should be hidden.

If user selects from the dropdownList inside the **OutOfState** DIV, then the other two DIVs need to be hidden.

Finally, by default, only the dropdownlist inside the **fromCity** DIV should be visible on page load.

Any ideas how to make this work?

Thanks alot in advance

Re: How do I show different options based on selected value from dropdownList?

a few seconds ago|LINK

Thanks a lot A2H,

Since I feel a bit more comfortable with jQuery, I tried the below code but it doesn't work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#tripType').change(function () {
        var SelectedValue = $('#<%= tripType.ClientID %> option:selected').val();

        if ((SelectedValue == 'one_way_to_airport') | (SelectedValue == 'one_way_from_airport') | (SelectedValue == 'round_trip_airport') | (SelectedValue == 'One-way trip NOT involving Airport') | (SelectedValue == 'Round trip NOT involving Airport')) {
            $('#fromCity').fadeIn();
            $('#WithinStateLimits').fadeOut();
            $('#OutOfState').fadeOut();
        }
        else if (value == 'hourly') {
            // Show or hide
            $('#fromCity').fadeOut();
            $('#OutOfState').fadeOut();
            $('#WithinStateLimits').fadeIn();
        }
        else { // value == 'Long_Distance'
            $('#fromCity').fadeOut();
            $('#WithinStateLimits').fadeOut();
            $('#OutOfState').fadeIn();
        }
    }); 
</script>

  <asp:DropdownList ID="tripType" runat="server" class="select ">
   <asp:ListItem value="">--Select One--</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="one_way_to_airport">One-way trip TO Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="one_way_from_airport">One-way trip FROM Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="round_trip_airport">Round trip involving Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="one_way_no_airport">One-way trip NOT involving Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="round_trip_no_airport">Round trip NOT involving Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="hourly">Hourly/Charter</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="Long_Distance">Long Distance</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropdownList>
```

Comment: use || for or not just | one

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef got it. Plus, `var SelectedValue = $("#tripType").val()` will also get you the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I FOUND the solution and here it is. I hope it helps someone else.

I used a combination of CSS and JQuery to hide or show divs depending on user's selection from tripTyype dropdownList.

So ensure that only fromCity div is shown on page load, I simply put the following on the two DIVs I would like to hide on page load:

style="display:none;"

Here is complete code:

```
    //js

function ShowHideDiv() {

        //Get dropdown selected value
        var SelectedValue = $('#<%= tripType.ClientID %> option:selected').val();


        // check selected value.
        if ((SelectedValue == 'one_way_to_airport') || (SelectedValue == 'one_way_from_airport') || (SelectedValue == 'round_trip_airport') || (SelectedValue == 'one_way_no_airport') || (SelectedValue == 'round_trip_no_airport')) {

            //If fromCity is selected then show from city div and hide other Divs 
            $('#fromCity').css("display", "block");
            $('#WithinStateLimits').css("display", "none");
            $('#OutOfState').css("display", "none");

        }
        else if (SelectedValue == 'hourly') {

            //If hour is selected then show hourly div and hide other Divs 

            $('#fromCity').css("display", "none");
            $('#WithinStateLimits').css("display", "block");
            $('#OutOfState').css("display", "none");

       }
        else {

            //If out of state is selected then show the out of state Div and hide the others.

            $('#fromCity').css("display", "none");
            $('#WithinStateLimits').css("display", "none");
            $('#OutOfState').css("display", "block");

        }

    }

</script>

//markup:

 <table>
  <tr>
   <td>
    <label for="tripType">Trip Type <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
      <asp:DropdownList ID="tripType" runat="server" class="select " onchange="ShowHideDiv();"> 
   <asp:ListItem value="">--Select One--</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="one_way_to_airport">One-way trip TO Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="one_way_from_airport">One-way trip FROM Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="round_trip_airport">Round trip involving Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="one_way_no_airport">One-way trip NOT involving Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="round_trip_no_airport">Round trip NOT involving Airport</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="hourly">Hourly/Charter</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="Long_Distance">Long Distance</asp:ListItem>
  </asp:DropdownList>
 </td>
 <td>
  <div id="fromCity">
  <label for="from_city_and_state">Pick off from <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="from_city_and_state" runat="server" class="select " >
     <asp:ListItem value="">--Select One--</asp:ListItem>
   </asp:DropDownList>
 </div>
 <div id="WithinStateLimits" style="display:none;" runat="server">
<label for="HourlyCharter">Hourly <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="HourlyCharter" runat="server" class="select ">
   <asp:ListItem value="3">3 Hours</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="4">4 Hours</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="5">5 Hours</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="6">6 Hours</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="7">7 Hours</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>

</div>
 <div id="OutOfState" style="display:none;">
<label for="LongDistance">Long Distance <abbr class="required" title="required">*</abbr></label>
<asp:DropDownList ID="LongDistance" runat="server" class="select ">
   <asp:ListItem value="2">$2 per mile</asp:ListItem>
   <asp:ListItem value="4">$4 per mile</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```